# Jetpack compose not recomposing view on value change

Tags: kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, objectbox

I am using objectbox and attempting to force recomp on my lazy column with information from the viewModel.

I currently use a method that has been state hoisted to the view model but can't seem to retrieve the value in the view model and force recomp.

[image: Data Field before being deleted]

[image: Data Field being deleted pop up dialog]

In my view model (DataFieldsViewModel), I've obtained all the Data Fields like this:

```
private val _dataFieldsBox = ObjectBox.get().boxFor(DataField::class.java)
var dataFieldsBox: Box<DataField> = _dataFieldsBox
```

and then it is passed in the composable screen using

```
fields = viewModel.dataFieldsBox
```

and the data fields object removed with

```
   is DataFieldEvent.ConfirmDelete -> {
                _deletedDataField.value = event.dataField
                _dataFieldsBox.remove(deletedDataField.value)
}
```

the reference for deletedDataField is kept so that it can be restored from a snack bar.

The delete works, the restore works, it's just that the lazy column does not update until I click another view that forces recomp. I've even mocked up a simple button with state hoisted increment and decrement methods and a value in the view model to test out recomp and got that working pretty quick, just don't know how to do it for these ObjectBox DataField objects

**Edit 18/08**
Tried using mutableStateOf

```
private var _dataFieldsBox = ObjectBox.get().boxFor(DataField::class.java)
    var dataFieldsBox = mutableStateOf(_dataFieldsBox)
```

and then attempting to collect the value with

```
val fields by viewModel.dataFieldsBox
```

and then deleting with

```
_deletedDataField.value = event.dataField 
_dataFieldsBox.remove(event.dataField)
```

only fix right now is the two hacky ways which i don't like. I read something about despite the values in a mutable list changing because the reference is the same the recomp doesn't happen to save on recomps.

So tried to amend the list and then duplicate with new values which also did nothing.

```
is DataFieldEvent.ConfirmDelete -> {
                _deletedDataField.value = event.dataField
                _dataFieldsBox.remove(event.dataField)
                val newList = _dataFieldsBox
                dataFieldsBox = mutableStateOf(newList)
            }
```

Comment: Please look on to my answer. 
Are you using state? Can you please update more code.  I can update my answer if you provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be helpful if you update viewmodel code you are having.

Not worked on ObjectBox. With your current code, here is the thing.
Composable function will recompose when it is able to listen to changes. For normal variable it does not listen to changes. You can make them listen in several ways.

You can do it with [mutableStateOf()](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state). You can have mutableState variable which takes type of _dataFieldsBox . And so can access it by viewModel._dataFieldsBox.value.

```
private val _dataFieldsBox = ObjectBox.get().boxFor(DataField::class.java
var _dataFieldsBox = mutableStateOf(_dataFieldsBox)


And then in view model, 
_dataFieldsBox.value.remove(_dataFieldsBox) // This will remove the value in the state variable and composable function will recompose.
```

You can also use LiveData and observe for the changes and it will recompose.

Comment: No Luck. Followed your instructions and changed it to a mutableStateOf and it did nothing different. I found two ways to cheat around it but i really don't like them as solutions.
1. another composable is toggled. This composable is one that i use to show a "no data" message, when the rows are showing its hidden. By forcing it to unhide then hide, my lazy column is recomposed
2. deleting the item in the fields object in the lazy column code when the delete dialog is called. This means though, that the confirm dialog message is basically useless as the item would have been deleted already